# Move discussion list to another discussion list

Tags: visual-studio, object-model

How to move a discussion list with all its messages to another discussion list maintaining the proper tree structure of the messages(replies)??

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about this, I think an old fashioned powershell based export list should do the job.

```
Export-SPWeb
```

Comment: I'm working on MOSS 2007 and I need to do this using object model